# How to get the String including white spaces

Tags: java, regex

I am using a pattern \s\s\s\s(.*) on a String "      XYX XYQ WQHY   ". So after using this pattern on this string the white spaces are trimmed.exactly starting four spaces should be removed but not the rest of white spaces.I am using this pattern in JAVA.

Comment: You need to show bit of your code with sample input/output strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to remove the first 4 spaces would be,

```
^\s{4}(.*)$
```

Java regex would be,

```
^\\s{4}(.*)$
```

Replacement string:

```
$1
```

Java code would be,

```
String s = "    XYX XYQ WQHY    ";
String m = s.replaceAll("^\\s{4}(.*)$", "$1");
System.out.println(m); //=>XYX XYQ WQHY
```

Like anubhava said in his comment, you could replaceFirst function.

```
String s = "    XYX XYQ WQHY    ";
String m = s.replaceFirst(" {4}", "");
System.out.println(m);
```

It removes the exact four spaces at the start.

Answer (score 1):

would this do?

```
newString = yourString.replaceAll("^ {4}","");
```

if you want to remove the leading 4 spaces **or Tabs**:

```
newString = yourString.replaceAll("^\\s{4}","");
```

Comment: Why not `replaceFirst`?

Comment: @anubhava yea, the replaceFirst is better for this replacement. mine (replaceAll) costs one more `find()` than the replaceFirst.